# How can I get the amount of month from days in js?

Tags: javascript, date

I would like to have an output like: x Months and x Days

```
var startDate       = new Date( '12/10/2015' );
var endDate     = new Date( '12/24/2016' );    
var days = parseInt((endDate - startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

with this, the output will be 380 (the number of the days between the two dates)
is there any way to get the ouput in this case: 12 Months an 15 Days?

thanks

Comment: Take a lok: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942895/convert-a-number-of-days-to-days-months-and-years-with-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript
You may find this useful